# How to deal with integer max difference between 32 bit and 64bit servers?

Tags: php, math, 32bit-64bit, uniqueidentifier

It takes a long time to figure out what was causing malfunctioning a website of mine when migrating to a better hosting subscription.

I use a 'self-made' uniqueId generator to generate everything that must be unique but this uniqueness is not random. I use this to communicate between several services, generate reproducible unique 'numbers' for files, articles and so on.

This is the function I have made and never had problems with (I think it never runs on a 64bit system before?) to generate an unique id. I know this uniqueness is limited (64.000) but never lead to a problem until now.

```
function suGetHashCode($s)
{
 $hash=0;
 $c=(is_string($s))?strlen($s):0;
 $i=0;
 while($i<$c) 
 {
   $hash = (($hash << 5)-$hash)+ord($s{$i++});
   //hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
 }
 return ( $hash < 0 )?(($hash*-1)+0xFFFFFFFF):$hash; // convert to unsigned int
} 

function suUniqueId( $s, $bAddLen = false )
{ 
  $i = base_convert( suGetHashCode( $s ), 10, 32 );
  if( $bAddLen && is_string($s) )
   { $i.=('-'.suGetLz( dechex( strlen($s)*4 ), 3 )); } 

  return $i; 
}

function suGetLz( $i, $iMaxLen ) // Leading zero
{
  if( !is_numeric( $i ) || $i < 0 || $iMaxLen <= 0 )
   { return $i; }
  $c = strlen( $i );
  while( $c < $iMaxLen )
   { $c++; $i='0'.$i; } 
  return $i;
}
```

The max int value of an integer is on the new system:

```
PHP_INT_MAX = 9223372036854775807
```

On other system(s) it is:

```
PHP_INT_MAX = 2147483647
```

Well, I am not a math person, I think this is causing the problem because of the 0xFFFFFFFF increment when negative (I think it will be never negative on this new system).

But how can I change the function that it produces the same unique id's like on other systems?

For example: 
It produces the same id for different strings on the new hosting server:

```
 $sThisUrl = '<censored>';
 var_dump( suUniqueId($sThisUrl) ); // Produce: 1l5kc37uicb  
 $sThisUrl = '<censored>';
 var_dump( suUniqueId($sThisUrl) ); // Produce the same id as above: 1l5kc37uicb
```

But, this must be like on older systems:

```
 $sThisUrl = '<censored>';
 var_dump( suUniqueId($sThisUrl) ); // Produce: a46q6nd  
 $sThisUrl = '<censored>';
 var_dump( suUniqueId($sThisUrl) ); // Produce: 2mirj1h
```

*Notice: The string is seperate into parts to avoid stackoverflow see this a link.*

**EDIT**: *Removed filenames*

Does anyone how to deal with this problem?

Comment: There's no point saying "edit: removed X" because it just draws attention to the original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19214266/1

Comment: In some way you are right but okay, put two different long urls in the example and you will see that it produce the same results when on 64bit.

Comment: You can't easily take back stuff you posted under cc-by-sa license. Editing the question will make it less visible, but the question in its original form is no longer your exclusive property. Furthermore, removing the strings makes it tricky for others to reproduce this problem. And since few people have 32bit and 64bit installs of PHP at hand, this greatly reduces the chances for comparisons.

Comment: @MvG: The point was that the function produces the same id, no matter what the input is, the urls where only an example. You can simply put some different urls into the example, the behaviour of the function stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you truncate after every character is processed:

```
$hash = (($hash << 5)-$hash)+ord($s{$i++});
$hash = $hash & 0xFFFFFFFF; // Convert to 32bit integer
```

At least on my 64bit system this leads to the desired `2mirj1h` in your second example, although without this modification I got `1c6ta2qjga7` and not `1l5kc37uicb` as you did.

I'd also change the return value to simply return `$hash`. Either it can represent unsigned 32bit numbers correctly, then the preceding mask should force that interpretation. Or your system can't represent these, then the added computation won't get you there either, and you'd have to split the number into bit groups and stringify them individually.

Of course, the easiest solution would be to use some well established common hashing algorithm, e.g. using [the `hash` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). Add some secret salt if you feat this might open you to attacks. If the result of such a hash code is too long, you can simply take part of the output. You can convert base any way you like, so you won't have to use the hexadecimal notation common for hashes. Using a cryptographic hash would also reduce chances of a conflict; for example in your case the document `generbM.js` in the same path would yield the same hash.

Comment: Thank you so much! All problems gone with this change. The reason I use this because the results it produce is not that huge like other hashes. I don't use it for security, for simple tasks, sometimes as checksum, sometimes as id or file identifier (temp or something) and between different platforms. Thanks again!

Comment: *If the result of such a hash code is too long, you can simply take part of the output* Thus no longer guaranteeing uniqueness...

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Hashes don't guarantee uniqueness, they are just designed such that accidential (and in the case of cryptographic hashes not so accidential) collisions are extremely unlikely. Reduce the size and the chances of a collision increase, but I'd still put far more trust in a truncated MD5 than any self-made stuff with the same output length (or same entropy, to be more precise and take different bases into account).

Comment: It is just a simple method and some other method to produce an identifier. For me it is just working OK. I use it maybe max 40 times to produce an unique id for something (in isolated matter). Never had problems with it until I migrate to 64bit. And when there is no problems with the generated id's there is no reason to switch right?

Comment: My mistake, I read your recommendation with OP's requirement for uniqueness in mind and confused hash with GUID.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would write a unit test to make sure that you get the same results on a 32 bit and a 64 bit machine for that one function.

The loop should be changed in something like this:

```
while($i<$c) 
{
  $hash = (($hash << 5)-$hash)+ord($s{$i++});
  hash = hash & 0xFFFFFFFF; // Convert to 32bit integer
}
$hash = ( $hash < 0 )?(($hash*-1)+0xFFFFFFFF):$hash; // convert to unsigned int
return $hash & 0xFFFFFFFF; // Convert to 32bit integer
```

Your Unit test can run against the original on the 32 bit version and save the output. Then run that on the 64 bit and compare with those 32 bit results. If any one is different, you know that you still don't have a 1 to 1 equivalent.

Comment: Similar to first answer but thanks anyway. Besides, the negative check is not needed because it runs on 64bit and can produce WORD.

Comment: He does not mention the `$hash & 0xFFFFFFFF` nor writing unit tests... Actually, he says you could just return $hash, but that could change the way it worked which, if you used that for a while would mean you have data in databases that relies on it so it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Well, i have read his post and get it to work. I mean, I understand the meaning of his post. Thanks anyway!

Comment: [Seems](http://ideone.com/utkdmp) you are right, the special treatment of negative values for the sake of consistency might be required. Stupid language, which apparently has *some* concept of unsigned integers, but as far as I can see not the language features to deal with it in a sensible way. Any language where a bitwise and with one positive operand can lead to a negative result should get shot…